# Header Redirect and Keep URL Parameters

Tags: php

I would like to do a `header('Location: pageB.php')` redirect from the current url which is:

`http://example.com/pageA.php?one=124214412&?two=ofisajfsa8938`

How do I keep the parameters after `http://example.com/pageB.php` after the header redirect?

I always end up with `http://example.com/pageB.php` instead of `http://example.com/pageB.php?one=124214412&?two=ofisajfsa8938`

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Location: pageB.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```